# How to stop calling the onDraw() function on a View?

Tags: android

Im clearing up the bitmaps i load in one activity before i more into the other activity.

eg:

```
pic1 = null;
System.gc();
nextActivityIntent = new Intent(ThisActivity,NextActivity.class);
ThisActivity.startActivityForResult(nextActivityIntent,123);
```

But the problem is system calls onDraw some times after i call "pic1=null". When it happens the application crashes with pointing a NullPoint Exception.

Cab any one suggest me how to stop calling onDraw() after setting the "pic1=null". Can i use synchornized to make this happen.

Comment: Maybe setting the visibility to gone? Just a wild guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `view.setWillNotDraw(true);` ([link here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setWillNotDraw%28boolean%29)), but I'm not sure it will prevent it.

On a side note, if your first activity will finish, there is no need to set the bitmap to null nor to call `System.gc();`. The bitmaps will be recovered anyway after the activity is destroyed.

If for some reason you still want to do it, you should do that inside the `onDestroy()` callback to avoid any drawing issues. Check the [Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Its not actually destroying. Its just moving into onPause state. Any way i managed to add a try catch inside the problem area and solved it.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how you solved this issue. I have also a similar situation, where I want to call ondraw only after a specif flag is set, else it should remain in pause state